# gUnaryUnion from rgeos packge fails randomly

Tags: r, geos, rgeos

I am using `gUnaryUnion()` function from the `rgeos` package to "melt" administrative regions into bigger units.

At times I do get the expected result, and other times (seemingly randomly, so I suspect a memory issue) it fails - the most common error message is :

```
Error in SpatialPolygons(pl, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(dots[[1]]))):  
    cannot get a slot ("coords") from an object of type "NULL"
```

The intriguing thing is that at other times it runs perfectly. I am positively certain that the object I run the Union on has CRS set. It is a sp object with size in the tens of megabytes, so not huge but sizeable.

Is there a way to work around this? Assign more memory to Geos for example? Tune some parameters?

An example of my problem is

```
library(RCzechia) # set of shapefiles for the Czech Republic - devtools::install_github("jlacko/RCzechia")
library(rgeos)
set_RGEOS_polyThreshold(1/1000)
set_RGEOS_dropSlivers(TRUE)
okresy <- RCzechia::okresy 
nuts <- okresy@data$KOD_CZNUTS3
kraje <- gUnaryUnion(okresy, nuts) # this fails!!
```

My session info is

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

rgeos version: 0.3-26, (SVN revision 560)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246 
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5 
 Polygon checking: TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on windows, with some warnings about minuscule polygons. The easier way to do this (because it keeps the attributes) is:

```
library(raster)
a <- aggregate(okresy, 'KOD_CZNUTS3')
```

But that should not help with your problem, as it uses rgeos under the hood.

This is my rgeos:

```
library(rgeos)
rgeos version: 0.3-25, (SVN revision 555)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.6.1-CAPI-1.10.1 r0 
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5 
 Polygon checking: TRUE
```

Comment: You nailed my biggest headache: the code indeed works on my Windows laptop, and so I am fairly certain it is not utterly wrong, but fails on my main server (where I need it to run in sort of production mode). Very annoying... :(

Comment: any chance you can update to a newer (r)geos on the server?

Comment: I will try. I have the geos library that came with the regular Ubuntu package, slightly out of date but not hopelessly so. About one minor version off. The `rgeos` package is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

by chance I am working also on Czech NUTS data, and when I tried to perform the same action (aggregate) I got, sometimes, the same error. Yes, the error is not always occurring and this is particularly annoying. However, I had the impression(!) that this could be due to the island polygon of NUTS region CZ02 (Prague), but happens in deed also for NUTS region CZ07. I do get sometimes error message:"Error in rgeos::gUnaryUnion(x) : comm2comment: buffer overflow" and
sometimes "Error in SpatialPolygons(pl, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(dots[[1]]))) : 
  cannot get a slot ("coords") from an object of type "NULL""
Did not find out yet the real reason

Comment: The Czech Republic is a complicated place... I plan to transfer the `RCzechia` package from `sp` to `sf` package format soon, and it should get easier.